# Hosting multiple web apps on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I running different multiple websites on an EC2 instance separated by vhost.conf but I sometimes run out of resources as some web apps consume more than others. Not only that, I also get experience down time if one site generates config errors in apache -> all servers will simply stop responding. The other thing is I also desire to run inginx and other web servers

My Supposing Solutions are:

1.To create an ECS instance and containerise each website on separate EC2 inside ECS, meaning I will have multiple instances of EC2 in ECS.

2.Create containers on an already existing EC2 for each site, but the downside is I will still have a single point of failure.

Kindly advise on the best approach and/or add on other suitable suggestions

Comment: Personally, I would not use ECS for a simple use case like this, especially since you don't seem to have a lot of experience. You are going to have a lot of pain with it. Try to keep it simple: why not run a single (smaller) EC2 instance per website first. This way you do what you already do and know and if one website needs more resources, you increase the size of its EC2 instance. This is defintely not the shiny and marketing compatible solution, but it is probably a lot simpler.

Comment: thank you @Jens will go with approach for now